# ltng:require on a sub component is not loading a Static Resource

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning

I was successfully loading a static resource into a Lightning component using the following ltng:require:

```
<ltng:require scripts="{!$Resource.SObjectSearchBar}" afterScriptsLoaded="{!c.createAndSetSearchbar}"/>
```

I split the Component in question into an extendable super component and a sub component. When the ltng:require is on the super component it runs no problem. When it's on the sub component it never runs the afterScriptsLoaded.

There's no error in my browser's console, the Salesforce developer console, nor on the page that uses the component. The network tab in my browser's console show's that it's at least getting to the static resource in Salesforce.

I've done some extensive googling, tried fiddling around with the way it calls the script, the location (super vs. sub component) of the afterScriptsLoaded method, calling the static resource via Aura, adding a ltng:require to both components, and I'm no closer to an answer. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Parent Component (SObjectSearchbar)

HTML:

```
<aura:component extensible="true">  

<aura:attribute name="searchbar" type="Object"/>
<aura:attribute name="SObjectSearchBar" type="Object"/>
<aura:attribute name="query" type="String" default=""/>
<aura:attribute name="intervalRunning" type="Boolean" default="false"/>
<aura:attribute name="extendInterval" type="Boolean" default="false"/>

<aura:attribute name="placeholder" type="String" default="- Please Select an Option -" />
<aura:attribute name="actionName" type="String" />
<aura:attribute name="SObject" type="String" />

<aura:handler event="c:SObjectSelected" action="{!c.updateFilter}"/> 
<aura:handler event="c:ClearSObjectSelection" action="{!c.handleClear}"/> 
<aura:registerEvent name="SObjectSelected" type="c:SObjectSelected"/>
<aura:registerEvent name="ClearSObjectSelection" type="c:ClearSObjectSelection"/>

<div style="position:relative">
    <ui:inputText placeholder="{!v.placeholder}" click="{!c.toggleDropdown}" keydown="{!c.searchSObjectList}" class="searchbarInput" value="{!v.searchbar.query}"/>
    <div aura:id="dropdown" class="slds-dropdown-trigger slds-dropdown-trigger_click searchbarInput searchbarDropdown slds-scrollable__x">
      <div class="slds-dropdown slds-dropdown_left slds-dropdown_length-7" style="width:20rem" onscroll="{!c.loadMoreResults}">
        <ul class="slds-dropdown__list" role="menu">
        <aura:iteration items="{!v.searchbar.displayList}" var="obj">
          <li class="slds-dropdown__item" role="presentation" > 
            <a href="javascript:void(0);" role="menuitem" tabindex="0">
              <span onclick="{!c.selectSObject}" title="{!obj.Name}" id="{!obj.salesforceId}">{!obj.searchableData}</span>
            </a>
          </li>
        </aura:iteration>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
</aura:component>
```

Controller:

```
({
toggleDropdown : function(component, event, helper){
    helper.toggleDropdown(component);
},   

loadMoreResults : function(component, event, helper){
    var searchbar = component.get('v.searchbar');
    var scrollTop = event.srcElement.scrollTop;
    var scrollHeight = event.srcElement.scrollHeight;
    var clientHeight = event.srcElement.clientHeight;
    if(searchbar.pointer < searchbar.sobjectList.length && !searchbar.scrollLock && scrollHeight - scrollTop <= (clientHeight + 25)){
        helper.loadResults(component, searchbar);
    }
},

searchSObjectList : function(component, event, helper){
    helper.clearSelectedId(component);
    helper.fireClearSObjectSelection(component);
    var searchbar = component.get('v.searchbar');
    var pressedKey = event.Ob.domEvent.key;
    if(pressedKey.length == 1){
        searchbar.query += pressedKey;
    }
    else{
        searchbar.query = '';
    }
    if(component.get('v.intervalRunning')){
        component.set('v.extendInterval', true);
    }
    else{
        component.set('v.intervalRunning', true);
        window.setTimeout($A.getCallback(function(){helper.runInterval(component, helper)}), 500);
    }   
},

selectSObject : function(component, event, helper){
    helper.updateSelectedId(component, event);
    helper.toggleDropdown(component);
    helper.fireSObjectSelected(component);
},

updateFilter : function(component, event, helper){

},

handleClear : function(component, event, helper){

}
})
```

Helper:

```
({
createSearchbar : function (component) {
    var searchbar = {sobjectList : [],
                     displayList : [],
                     displayIncrement : 15,
                     query : "",
                     pointer : 0,
                     selected : "",
                     scrollLock : false
                    };      
    component.set("v.searchbar", searchbar);
    component.set('v.SObjectSearchBar', new SObjectSearchBar());
    console.log('searchbar');
    console.log(searchbar);
},

getSObjects : function (component, action) { 
    action.setCallback(this,function(response){this.getSObjectsCallback(response,component);});
    $A.enqueueAction(action);   
},

getSObjectsCallback : function(response,component){
    if (response.getState() === "SUCCESS") {
        var returnValue = response.getReturnValue();
        if(returnValue){
            var searchbar = component.get("v.searchbar");
            searchbar.sobjectList = returnValue;
            var SObjectSearchBar = component.get("v.SObjectSearchBar");
            searchbar = SObjectSearchBar.incrementDisplayList(searchbar);
            component.set("v.searchbar", searchbar);
        }
    } else if (response.getState() === "ERROR") {
        console.log('initializeAccount failure');
        $A.log("Errors", response.getError());
    }
},

toggleDropdown : function(component){
    var dropdownId = component.get('v.dropdownId');
    var searchbarDropdown = component.find(dropdownId);
    $A.util.toggleClass(searchbarDropdown, 'slds-is-open');
},   

loadResults : function(component, searchbar){
    searchbar.scrollLock = true;
    var SObjectSearchBar = component.get('v.SObjectSearchBar');
    searchbar = SObjectSearchBar.incrementDisplayList(searchbar);
    component.set('v.searchbar', searchbar);
},

runInterval : function(component, helper){
    var searchbar = component.get('v.searchbar');
    if(component.get('v.extendInterval')){
        component.set('v.extendInterval', false);
        window.setTimeout($A.getCallback(function(){helper.runInterval(component, helper)}), 500);

    }
    else{
        searchbar = this.performSearch(component, searchbar);
        component.set('v.intervalRunning', false);
    }
    component.set('v.searchbar', searchbar);        
},

performSearch : function(component, searchbar){
    var SObjectSearchBar = component.get('v.SObjectSearchBar');
    searchbar.displayList = [];
    searchbar.pointer = 0;
    searchbar = SObjectSearchBar.incrementDisplayList(searchbar);       
    return searchbar;
},

updateSelectedId : function(component, event){
    var searchbar = component.get('v.searchbar');
    var selectedId = event.srcElement.id;
    var selectedName = event.srcElement.title;
    searchbar.query = selectedName;
    searchbar.selected = selectedId;
    component.set('v.searchbar', searchbar);
},

clearSelectedId : function(component){
    var searchbar = component.get('v.searchbar');
    searchbar.selected = '';
    component.set('v.searchbar', searchbar);
}z

fireSObjectSelected : function(component){
    var sobject = component.get('v.SObject');
    var searchbar = component.get('v.searchbar');
    var selectedId = searchbar.selectedId;

    var action = $A.get('e.c:SObjectSelect');
    action.setParams({'sobjectType' : sobject, 'salesforceId' : selectedId});
    action.fire();
},

fireClearSObjectSelection : function(component){
    var sobject = component.get('v.SObject');
    var action = $A.get('e.c:ClearSObjectSelection');
    action.setParams({'sobjectType' : sobject});
    action.fire();
}
})
```

Child Component (AccountSearchbar)

HTML:

```
<aura:component controller="AccountSearchbarController" extends="c:SObjectSearchbar" >  
    <ltng:require scripts="{!$Resource.SObjectSearchBar}" afterScriptsLoaded="{!c.createAndSetSearchbar}"/>
</aura:component>
```

Controller:

```
createAndSetSearchbar : function(component, event, helper){
    console.log('sub');
    helper.createSearchbar(component);

    var action = component.get('c.getSearchbarAccounts');   
    helper.getSObjects(component, action);        
},
```

Static Resource:

```
window.SObjectSearchBar = function() {
var incrementDisplayList = function(searchbar) {
    var sobjectList = searchbar.sobjectList;
    var displayList = searchbar.displayList;
    var displayIncrement = searchbar.displayIncrement;
    var query = searchbar.query;
    var pointer = searchbar.pointer;
    var addedSObjects = 0;
    var matchesQuery;
    while(pointer < sobjectList.length && addedSObjects < displayIncrement){    
        if(!query){
            matchesQuery = true;
        }   
        else{
            matchesQuery = this.searchTermsInData(sobjectList[pointer].searchableData, query);
        }   

        if(matchesQuery){
            displayList.push(sobjectList[pointer]); 
            addedSObjects++;                
        }       
        pointer++;  
    }
    searchbar.displayList = displayList;
    searchbar.pointer = pointer;
    searchbar.scrollLock = false;
    return searchbar;
};

var searchTermsInData = function(searchableData, query) {
    var searchTerms = query.split(" ");
    for (var searchTerm of searchTerms){
        if(!searchableData.toLowerCase().includes(searchTerm.toLowerCase())){
            return false;                
        }
    }
    return true;
};

var getSObjectFromList = function(sobjectList, sobjectID){
    for(var i in sobjectList){
        if(sobjectList[i].salesforceId == sobjectID){
            return sobjectList[i];
        }
    }
    return null;
};

return{
    incrementDisplayList : incrementDisplayList,
    searchTermsInData : searchTermsInData,
    getSObjectFromList : getSObjectFromList
};
```

}

Comment: Not sure if I have an answer for you yet, but would like to see more code. Ideally most of the relevant pieces of both components

Comment: I've added more of the code. Please let me know if you need more information. Thanks for the response!

Comment: Are these classes on the parent or the child component? Also, What about the markup of both parent and child?

Comment: The helper methods are in the parent component. The controller method has been in just the parent component, just the child component, both components at the same time, nothing has worked. The child had only the component tags (with a server side controller) and the ltng:require tag. There was quite a bit more in the parent component, but it never had any issues. The rest of the HTML rendered properly regardless of the static resource. I can post it if you'd like, not sure how helpful it'll be though.

Comment: Ryan, I am not sure I follow. The more code you post, the better.

Comment: Just added the full code of my components. There might be a few minor differences, since I've headed in a different direction, but this should be about the same. So, about the location of createAndSetSearchbar. Initially it was in both the child and parent controller. I was under the impression that this would just override the parent method with the child's method. When it didn't work, I wanted to check if it could be causing issues, so I tried it with the method in just the parent controller, and then just the child controller. Nothing has worked so far. Hope that clears things up a little.

Comment: Are both your components the same API version?

Comment: I just checked. They are both the same API version: 39.